# WebSocket immediately disconnects - Openshift

Tags: java, sockets, websocket, openshift, java-websocket

The `WebSocket` is working perfectly in localhost (tomcat) . but when i host (Openshift - tomcat) it immediately disconnects and not firing the `onMessage` method. I've checked the header and the status code is `Status Code:101 Switching Protocols`.

Here is my socket.

```
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;


@ServerEndpoint("/TestSocket")
public class TestSocket {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String message) {
        System.out.println("New message : " + message);
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Message received -> :" + message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose() {
        System.out.println("Closed");
    }

}
```

Here is the live socket [ws://shifar-shifz.rhcloud.com:8000/MyTestProject/testWebSocket](http://ws://shifar-shifz.rhcloud.com:8000/MyTestProject/testWebSocket). I can't figure out what the problem is. Please help me.

**EDIT**

I am using the **Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)** cartridge. The project was deployed through a `WAR` file.

Answer (score 1):

I found it's working when i remove the **web-socket-api.jar** from the `lib` after the artifact building. I think the Openshift already contain another **web-socket-api.jar** in their server. and can't contain any duplicate of the existing `jars/libs`.